# Analytic continuation possible here?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, fourier-series, analytic-continuation

Consider a function $f(z)$ defined for all complex $z$ within the open unit circle.

More precisely
$$f(z) = a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \cdots$$
where the $a_n$ are complex numbers.

So $f(z)$ is a Taylor series with radius at least $1$ and thus $f(z)$ is analytic within the unit circle.

$f(z)$ is also bounded within the open unit circle.

Now for $|q| = 1$, $f(q)$ is also bounded.

Let $q = \exp(2 \pi t i)$
and thus $f(q) = f(\exp(2 \pi t i))$ for real $t$.

Now we have that
$$f(\exp(2 \pi t i)) = \cos(g(t)) + i \sin(g(t)) $$
for a 2pi periodic real $g(t)$.

So it follows that $|f(q)| = 1$

Also we require $g(t)$ to be $C^{\infty}$ over the reals $t$.
(This implies that $f(q)$ and $g(t)$ are both fourier series)

Further $f(z) \neq c * id(z)^ k$ for some integer $k$ and some complex $|c| = 1$ or $c=0$.

So far the definition and requirements for $f(z)$.

Now the questions:

What are examples of $f(z)$?

Can the radius of $f(z)$ be larger than $1$?

If the radius is $1$, is it still possible to have analytic continuation?
(so the unit circle is not a natural boundary)

Comment: any holomorphic function on the unit disc that satisfies $|f(z)| \to 1, |z| \to 1$ (in particular if it's continuous and of modulus $1$ on the boundary) is a finite Blaschke product so is a (specific kind of) rational function

Comment: @Conrad Thanks ! So we found all meromorphic functions on $C$ I guess.

Comment: Not quite all - finite Blaschke products are very specific ones; finite products of disc automorphisms so for example all the roots are inside the unit disc and all poles are $1/\bar w$ for any $w \neq 0$ root

Comment: Your condition is $|f(z)|=1$ for $|z|=1$ That implies (it's a well known theorem of Rado and not hard to prove) that $f$ is a finite Blaschke product so it has finitely many zeroes inside the unit circle and finitely many poles determined by those zeroes outside; infinite Blaschke products satisfy the relation above almost everywhere only and they fail to be defined at least one point on the unit circle; more generally inner functions satisfy the above ae

Comment: @Conrad yes you are right, sorry.

Comment: @Conrad You said, not all. So what are examples of non-Blaschke products that are meromorphic on the whole complex plane ?

Comment: $1/(1-z)$ is not a Blaschke product nor is $1/(z-2)$; a finite Blaschke product is very specific - up to a constant of modulus one it's a finite product of $\frac{\alpha-z}{1-\bar \alpha z}, |\alpha|<1$; the finite Blaschke products are exactly the functions that are analytic inside the unit disc and continuous and of modulus one on the unit circle

Comment: @Conrad yes but $1/(1 - z)$ does not satisfy the requirements from the question, so it is not a solution ? You said " Not quite all " so there are meromorphic on C non-Blaschke products that satisfy the requirements of the OP ?

Comment: Again I think that is a miscommunication - what I meant is that the requirements imply the results are finite Blaschke products so rational functions, but that not all rational functions are finite Blaschke products; the only condition needed for a function to be a finite Blaschke product is that $f$ analytic inside the unit disc and $|f(z)| \to 1, |z| \to 1$ which is obviously implied by $f$ continuous and $|f(z)|=1$ on the unit circle

Comment: @Conrad oh ! Yes we misunderstood each other.

Comment: @Conrad if it is only holomorphic on the OPEN unit disk but not ON the entire unit disk , could we avoid having multiple zero's within the unit disk ?

Comment: not sure what the question is or what having multiple zeroes has to do with boundary behavior

Comment: @Conrad I just wonder if those zero's are " forced "

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean by forced; analytic functions inside the open unit disc can have pretty much any zero set one wants assuming it accumulates only at the boundary; the more conditions you put on the function, the more restricted is the zero set (eg if you want the function to be bounded, you need the zero set to satisfy the Blaschke condition $\sum (1-|z_n|) <\infty$), if the function stays away from zero at the boundary, the zero set is finite; similarly under very general conditions, analytic functions have radial limits ae so they have a sort of "boundary" value